# Field of polynomials and field of fractions

Tags: ring-theory

I have a very stupid question but really confused between the two symbols: can anybody make me understand the difference between the polynomial ring $R [X]$ and the other one $R(X)$ - I know the former one but confused with the later symbol.
My second question is: in order to show that a field $K$ is the field of fraction of an integral domain $R$, is it enough to show that $K $ is the smallest field containing  $R $ ?

Comment: Do you have a definition of $R(x)$?

Comment: $K (X)$ ={ P(X)/Q (X):  P(X),Q (X) are in K [X] }  is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adressing the second question, let $U \subset F $ be any field containing $R$. Then the inverse of each $\dfrac{a}{1} \in R$ is in $U$, so, for any $a,b\in R$, $\dfrac{a}{1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{b} = \dfrac{a}{b} \in U$, thus $F = U$. We conclude that $F$ is the smallest field containing $R$.